# Java newbie facing elementary problems

Tags: java

I'm a total newbie when it comes to programming and I'm writing in Java for the first time. It's for an assignment in college. I'm using NetBeans.

You see I'm completely lost and have no idea what I could do to fix my problem. This is the problem I'm facing:

1:
     `for (String edge : edges.elementSet())` - It says it cannot find the symbol 'elementSet'. What do I have to do to solve this problem?

2:
     `myConnections.addAll(y.getListOfLinks(tagsOfTheCurrentPictureAsAnArray));` - Here, it says it cannot find the symbol `'tagsOfTheCurrentPictureAsAnArray'`, but I mentioned it before:

```
String[] tagsOfTheCurrentPictureAsAnArray = tagsOfTheCurrentPicture.split(",");
for (String x : tagsOfTheCurrentPictureAsAnArray) {
```

What did I do wrong here?
Full script:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    String myFile = "C:\\Users\\Nils\\Desktop\\Uni\\Let's go Digital\\Digital data in practise\\Lecture4\\Datasets\\WWII.csv";
    FileWriter myFileWriter = new FileWriter("C:\\nodes.txt");
    BufferedWriter myBufferedNodesWriter = new BufferedWriter(myFileWriter);
    FileWriter myEdgesWriter = new FileWriter("C:\\edges.txt");
    BufferedWriter myBufferedEdgesWriter = new BufferedWriter(myFileWriter);
    FileReader myFileReader = new FileReader(myFile);
    BufferedReader myBufferedReader = new BufferedReader(myFileReader);
    String Comma = ",";
    char Commaderps = Comma.charAt(0);
    CsvReader excellentCsvReader;
    excellentCsvReader = new CsvReader(myBufferedReader, Commaderps);
    String textDelimiter = "\"";
    char Backslash = textDelimiter.charAt(0);
    excellentCsvReader.setTextQualifier(Backslash);
    excellentCsvReader.setUseTextQualifier(true);
    excellentCsvReader.readRecord();
    HashMultiset<String> myTags = HashMultiset.create();
    HashMultiset<String> myConnections = HashMultiset.create();
    while (excellentCsvReader.readRecord()) {
        String[] values = excellentCsvReader.getValues();
        String tagsOfTheCurrentPicture = values[2];
        String[] tagsOfTheCurrentPictureAsAnArray = tagsOfTheCurrentPicture.split(",");
        for (String x : tagsOfTheCurrentPictureAsAnArray) {
            myTags.add(x);
        }
        myBufferedNodesWriter.write("Id,Label,Number");
        myBufferedNodesWriter.newLine();
        for (String tag : myTags) {
            myBufferedNodesWriter.write(tag);
            myBufferedNodesWriter.write(",");
            myBufferedNodesWriter.write(tag);
            myBufferedNodesWriter.write(",");
            myBufferedNodesWriter.write(myTags.count(tag));
            myBufferedNodesWriter.newLine();
        }
        myBufferedNodesWriter.close();
        myBufferedEdgesWriter.write("Id,Source,Target,Type,Weight");
        myBufferedEdgesWriter.newLine();
        Integer idEdge = 0;
        for (String edge : edges.elementSet()) {
            idEdge = idEdge + 1;
            myBufferedEdgesWriter.write(idEdge);
            myBufferedEdgesWriter.write(",");
            myBufferedEdgesWriter.write(edge);
            myBufferedEdgesWriter.write(",");
            myBufferedEdgesWriter.write("Undirected");
            myBufferedEdgesWriter.write(",");
            myBufferedEdgesWriter.write(String.valueOf(edges.count(edge)));
            myBufferedEdgesWriter.newLine();
        }
        myBufferedEdgesWriter.close();
    }
    Utils y = new Utils();
    myConnections.addAll(y.getListOfLinks(tagsOfTheCurrentPictureAsAnArray));
    System.out.println("Tag:" + tagsOfTheCurrentPictureAsAnArray[3]);

}
```

}

Comment: The title of a question is meant to give a resume of the problem.

Comment: By the way, if you think I left out information you think you'll need to answer this question, please let me know.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis he's working with elements - maybe the title is a pun!?

Comment: What class is the "edges" object? If it's your code, show it

Comment: you need to provide more code so we have some idea of what is going on.

Comment: Doesn't seem like the most friendly of tasks for someone encountering the language for the very first time! Naughty lecturer.

Comment: Referring to your other question (which you acknowledged no answers for) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19126104/how-to-solve-this-arrayindexoutofboundsexception/19126164#19126164 this really sounds like you should go back to the drawing board - there's no way you're going to fix this.

Comment: For #1, without knowing what an `edges` is, it's impossible to answer. Possibly a spelling issue. For #2, without any context, it's impossible to answer. Probably a scoping issue.

Comment: Sorry, this is the first time I visit Stackoverflow.com. Furthermore, I'm not sure how to give a resume of my problem, because I can't properly specify what my problem actually is.

Comment: @user2836543 It's that the compiler can't find some symbols, just like the error message you state. But without context, we cannot identify *why* this might be the case.

Comment: We can't help help you if we don't have more context.  Try to put together a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/), and don't forget to make sure that it actually demonstrates your error.

Comment: @user2836543 if you copied and pasted into the title, the error message that you get, than it would be fine

Comment: Just added the remaining script. If you find another related question...this could be because there's more people working on this assignment. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: we still don't know where `edges` comes from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I see where your `tagsOfTheCurrentPictureAsAnArray` issue is

```
while (excellentCsvReader.readRecord()) {
    ...
    String[] tagsOfTheCurrentPictureAsAnArray = tagsOfTheCurrentPicture.split(",");
    for (String x : tagsOfTheCurrentPictureAsAnArray) {
        myTags.add(x);
    }
    ...
}
Utils y = new Utils();
myConnections.addAll(y.getListOfLinks(tagsOfTheCurrentPictureAsAnArray));
```

That last time you use it, it will be out of scope, because it's outside of your `while` loop.  if you want it to persist after your while loop, you have to declare it outside of your while loop.

so you want either

```
String[] tagsOfTheCurrentPictureAsAnArray = tagsOfTheCurrentPicture.split(",");
while (excellentCsvReader.readRecord()) {
    ...
```

if you want the same array for each iteration, or

```
String[] tagsOfTheCurrentPictureAsAnArray;
while (excellentCsvReader.readRecord()) {
    ...
    tagsOfTheCurrentPictureAsAnArray = tagsOfTheCurrentPicture.split(",");
```

if you want to re-initialize it at each iteration

Comment: Great! Thanks Sam, that's one problem down. Also, thanks for showing me how to fix the problem. Just telling me how to fix my problems won't help me just yet, sadly. I'll keep trying!

Answer (score 0):

Please post the entire code. Some guesses:

1) The class of `edges` does not have a method called `elementSet`. Is the method name spelt correctly? Is `edges` of the correct type?

2) Is `tagsOfTheCurrentPictureAsAnArray` declared? If it is, is it declared in the scope of the usage?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, it is spelled correctly, but it's probably just a silly thing I forgot. I'll ask my teacher to direct me next time I see him. As for your second question, it's just been answered. I'm pleasantly surprised by this community by the way. The feedback is really helpful and comes very quickly!

Answer (score 0):

Since your second question has been answered i will target the 1st one.
The problem is simple, there is no variable of type String[] named "edges".

```
for(String edge : edges.elementSet())
```

is "for every element of type String in the container named edges, do something". So the compiler looks for the container named edges, and cant find it (cause it doesn't exist).

For example, some lines before that you have a looping over myTags.
This doesnt throw any error since you do have a declaration for that variable:

```
HashMultiset<String> myTags = HashMultiset.create();
```

So all you have to do is provide annother such statement for the "edges"
set.

Furthermore, consider using functions to make your code more comprehensible.